# How does $f(x+\delta x)=(1+\delta x)f(x)\implies \frac{d f(x)}{dx}=f(x)$ generalizes to multivariables?

Tags: derivatives

I am looking for two generalizations:

1. Multivariable (with scalars)

$$
f(x+\delta x,y+ \delta y)=(1+\delta x + \delta y)f(x,y)\implies \frac{f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y)}{(\delta x +\delta y)}=f(x,y)
$$

Is this a derivative in some sense?

2. Multivariable (with vectors)

$$
f(x+\delta x,y+ \delta y)=(1+ \hat{\mathbf{x}} \delta x + \hat{\mathbf{y}} \delta y)f(x,y)\implies \frac{f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y)}{(\hat{\mathbf{x}}  \delta x + \hat{\mathbf{y}} \delta y)}=f(x,y)
$$

Do any of these generalizations connect to known derivatives?

Comment: Presumably, you want $f(x,y)$ on the right side of the equalities.

Comment: What is $\hat x,\hat y?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The notation $\hat x$ often denotes a unit vector along the $x$ direction.

Comment: But you can't divide by vectors, @MarkViola, as the OP clearly does.

Comment: @anon21 What are you trying to do?  For $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f\in C^2$, the equation $f'(x)=f(x)$ can be written $f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)=f'(x)\Delta x+o(\Delta x)=f(x)\Delta x+o(\Delta x)$ or $f(x+\Delta x)=(1+\Delta x)f(x)+o(\Delta x)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes.  I thought that you were asking about the notation $\hat x$.

Comment: A good sign that you're going to be in trouble is that this is undefined when $\delta x + \delta y = 0$. If you changed to something like $\sqrt{(\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2}$, then it would resemble a directional derivative.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, notice that:
$$\begin{align}
\phantom{=}&f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y)\\
=&\delta x\underbrace{\frac{f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y+\delta y)}{\delta x}}_{\approx\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y+\delta y)}}+\delta y\underbrace{\frac{f(x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y)}{\delta y}}_{\approx\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(x,y)}}
\end{align}$$
so it looks like the total derivative, which is:
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$